# What if to-be-created Office owner files already exist by name

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, ownership

As we know, MS Office applications like Excel and Word create Owner-files that start with ~$[...].extension 
For example: 
A Word-Document called "MyWordFile.docx" would get an owner file called "~$WordFile.docx".

**What if there is a file called "~$WordFile.docx" before the user opens "MyWordFile.docx" allready?**

*Please note that Words replaces the first two letters with "~$". So the owner-file-name of "MyWordFile.docx" would be "~$WordFile.docx"*

I tried it and no other file appears. Does Word then not create an owner file?

Edit: I checked [This documentation link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/211632/description-of-how-word-creates-temporary-files) but could not find an answer to my question.

Comment: So, I'm sure you *didn't* mean it, but you are comparing **MyWordFile.docx** with **WordFile.docx**. You did make sure the files were indeed *named* the same thing, right?

Comment: Yup I did.
But word seems to **replace the first two letters** with ~$. Excel on the other hand just puts ~$ in front of the rest of the name.